# no privileges on tablespace system

Tags: sql, oracle

I create a table and in the tabelnamespace = SYSTEM

when I go to insert I get an error

```
insert into  mytable(IDENTIFIER ) values ('test')

 08:35:17.120   DBMS    db.world -- ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSTEM'
```

any ideas?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36373/ora-01950-no-privileges-on-tablespace-system-what-error-is-it

Answer (score 0):

Your user doesn't have any quota on the system tablespace.

```
alter user <your user> quota 50m on system;
```